# Bandwidth throttling with OMATPE

Tags: java, netty

My web server (custom built on top of Netty) uses a web client (also custom built with Netty) to make proxied requests to S3.

```
Client -> Webserver|Webclient -> S3
```

The purpose of the system is to pipe file uploads directly to S3 with a little bit of logic:

- `Webserver` accepts client request (POST);
- Sets `Client` channel readability to false and verifies a bunch of stuff;
- When everything is successfully verified, it uses the `Webclient` to connect to `S3`;
- When the `Webclient` connects to `S3`:

  1. it sends a 100-Continue back to the client
  2. it sets `Client` channel readability to true
- From there on, all chunks received by the `Webserver` are handed over to the `Webclient` to forward.

In the (highly unlikely) event that the connection between `Client` and `Webserver` is faster than the connection between `Webclient` and `S3`, I need to throttle the connection between `Client` and `Webserver`.

The approach I took was simply keep a counter of bytes received by the `Webserver` (which increments every time `Client` sends data) and that decrements every time that a write of `Webclient` completes. Whenever the amount of data on this buffer goes over a given threshold, the `Client`'s channel readability is set to `false`.

This works great until I add an `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` to the server's pipeline.

A simple solution is to use an `OioClientSocketChannelFactory` on the `Webclient`. This causes the calls to `Channel.write` to be blocking, so when `messageReceived()` is called on the `Webserver`'s handler — and, consequently `Channel.write` is called on the `Webclient` — throttling happens "naturally".

However, if I use a `NioClientSocketChannelFactory` on the `Webclient`, then calls to `Channel.write` become asynchronous and throttling stops working.

Basically what I'm noticing here is that `Channel.setReadability(false)` seems to bear no effect when an `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` is inserted into the pipeline.

How can I perform throttling using OMATPE in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor also monitors the channel memory (in your case received data size) and suspend/enable reading when it above/below the configured max size (through OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor constructor).

2) When its used with an ExecutionHandler, the handler may discards channel state events, if some attachment found in the context (But that context attachment is usually set by OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, to not allow above upstream handlers to change the channel state and cause OutofMemoryException ).

```
            boolean readSuspended = ctx.getAttachment() != null;
            if (readSuspended) {
                // Drop the request silently if MemoryAwareThreadPool has
                // set the flag.
                e.getFuture().setSuccess();
                return;
            }
```

I think, you have to configure min, max channel memory size of OMATPE, or you may have an context attachment leads to this situation?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using any attachments. So I guess with OMATPE, I don't even need to perform bandwidth throttling on my top level handler, right?

Comment: It depends on how the data transfer happens between Webserver-> WebClient pipline. I think, use of OMATPE is to avoid OutOfMemoryException due to fast read + SEDA like pipline.

Comment: I think, to get it working add your channel handler which monitors the traffic before OMATPE in the server pipeline will solve the issue. Have a look on org.jboss.netty.handler.traffic.ChannelTrafficShapingHandler.

Answer (score 2):

As Jestan said, please refer to `org.jboss.netty.handler.traffic.ChannelTrafficShapingHandler` in the master.  Also, you will have to configure your `receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory` so that it does not return too large value.  Otherwise, Netty will just allocate a large buffer and fill it really quickly.  Use `AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory` with a smaller maximum in combination with `ChannelTrafficShapingHandler`.